# Limit custom post type to the authors only on front-end!

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, query-posts, author

I'm trying to limit the custom-post-types to their authors excluding administers on the homepage. This is how the code looks like on the homepage.php

```
  <?php 

          $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'project',
          'post_status' => 'publish'
          );

          $post_query = new WP_Query ( $args ); ?>

          <?php while($post_query->have_posts()):$post_query->the_post(); ?>

     //display post type content

          <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I tried using the code below, that almost achieved what i wanted but it is giving an unusual 404 error instead of the homepage for the new users(authors) but works absolutely fine when logged-in as administrator or from old author's profile before adding this code.

```
// limit post display to post authors
function limit_post_to_only_author($query) {
    global $current_user;
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        $query->set('author', $current_user->ID);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'limit_post_to_only_author');
```

I've posted a question with detailed explanation about the issue that the above code is causing [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/368611/limit-authors-to-their-own-posts-on-front-end-excluding-admins?noredirect=1#comment535267_368611). but would prefer a solution to limit the post to authors on the frontend...

Comment: The code is working as it is intended , The home page is not created by any of the authors , so it restricts them from viewing it . As admins are exempted they can view all pages including home page .  Try the code below ( it works in twentytwenty )

Comment: ` function app_output_buffer() {
  ob_start();
} 
add_action('init', 'app_output_buffer');

function set_only_author($query) {

 if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
  $query->set('author', get_current_user_id());
       
        if(is_404()) {
            wp_redirect(get_author_posts_url( get_current_user_id()));
                    }

    }
    }
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'set_only_author'); `